# Backup Monitoring Solution

Tags: backup, monitoring

I've been testing out different backup software across our environment and the one thing that I can't seem to get a handle on is the monitoring of these backup solutions.  I can't find one backup system that does **everything** that I want it to do, so I have a feeling that I'm going to end up with a few different pieces of software.

**With that said, is there any sane way to monitor disparate backup solutions?**

The only thing I've been able to find thus far that is completely agnostic is [PRTG’s IMAP Sensor](http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/47023-how-can-i-monitor-my-backup-software-to-be-sure-backup-succeeded-last-night).  I realize this is not a solution that should be solved by parsing email subjects/bodies, but I don't really know what else to do.  Has anyone had experience with this product for this purpose and is it effective?

Comment: I am somewhat afraid this question might be close because it is overly broad, and somewhat vague.  But the question certainly seems useful.

Comment: What do you want monitoring to pick up? My previous workplace kept a keen eye out for failed backup jobs, but had about a 60% success rate of using said backups when needed

Comment: I'm actually just looking to make sure they run successfully.  I don't need to monitor integrity checks or anything like that.

Comment: You can use CheckCentral for this: https://www.checkcentral.cc

Answer (score 7):

I am a nagios user, and so my method for monitoring my backups (Veeam, Windows Server Backup, Dirvish, mysqldump script,etc) basically amounts to using a passive service, and send_nsca to report the results of a check.

Basically for each backup technology I have written a script that is either called as part of the backup finished **hook in the backup system**, or scheduled to run after completion.  The various scripts check exit status, logs, size and so on, and then reports the status to the nagios passive service.  The service is set to alert if no status update is received within a defined time period.  Exactly what you need to monitor about each service is going to depend on your environment, and the software.

I am sure other monitoring systems must have similar things to a passive service.

Comment: Who'd a thunk it?  That's exactly what I do, too!

Comment: I do something similar with zabbix_sender.

Comment: I have a powershell script that checks Windows Server Backup via nsclient++.  :D

Comment: This was my first thought: Use the backup system to backup and use a monitoring system to monitor. With Zabbix, you could do proactive checks, end-of-process hooks, log parsing, etc. As well, backups should be part of what you are monitoring - drive sizes, services running, site responsiveness, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So for me, it's always been a lazy man's approach here if you are the only person responsible for monitoring the backups and that instant notification isn't a requirement, ie you don't need to fix the issue right when it occurs.

What I do is setup each of the backup software packages to send notifications via email to me.

Then I did the following:

1. Create a rule to move these notifications to a different folder in Outlook
2. Create another rule to search either the subject or body or similar (depends on the backup software's way of formatting the notifications) to look for things like "failed" or "incomplete" or similar and have that rule flag the message follow for Today.  I also have it create a copy in another folder called "Failed Backup Notifications".

Then when I check my email the next morning I can immediately see any flags or just check the "Failed Backup Notifications" folder.

(One note of caution.  I STILL recommend some other means of manually checking the backup programs at least once a week.  I say this because if the backups aren't running AT ALL even those the service/job scheduler seems to be running then you won't even get notification emails.  You should also have rules setup to alert you if you get an email such as "the Backup job engine service has stopped/failed" or similar)

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit that this was precisely how I was going to handle this.  I think we must administer similar environments, but I'd agree that this is not the optimal solution.  I'd love something like Zoredache is proposing, but I'm not sure that's what I'll end up going with.

Comment: @pk. in my experience there typically isn't time and usually you are the only one that even cares. :)  Good luck mate!